# Extract and graph information from a days-hours-minutes-seconds format

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates

I'm working in Google Sheets, and I have data for race finish times in "8d 3h 40m 13s" format and I'm want to extract that information so I can plot it in a chart.  Any ideas for how to achieve this?  I'm not an expert on Google Sheets so any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: what exactly you want to plot in chart/graph? and what chart/graph you want to go with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User0 did an amazing job of breaking down how to convert your race times into different durations that can be used to create a graph.

You will need to use one of those formulas (i would suggest the last one which is in seconds), so cut this:

=INT(TO_TEXT(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1, " "), "\d+"))),
 "select (Col1*24)+Col2 label (Col1*24)+Col2''")&":"&
 JOIN(":", QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1, " "), "\d+")),
 "select Col3,Col4")))*86400)

and add it to the column beside your list of race times. It is important with an array formula not to press enter, you MUST press  Ctrl + Shift + Enter (Cmd + Shift + Enter on a Mac) and Google Sheets will add the ArrayFormula. Then copy the formula down so there is one beside every race time, again press Ctrl + Shift + Enter.

If that worked okay you should see the amount of seconds beside each racetime, if not please start again from the beginning.

If you have a suitable list of converted race times, you can create a graph and use the column with seconds as the data range.

Answer (score 0):

- to extract numbers from the string:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1, " "), "\d+"))
  ```

  [image: 0]
- to create duration:

  ```
  =QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1, " "), "\d+"))),
   "select (Col1*24)+Col2 label (Col1*24)+Col2''")&":"&
   JOIN(":", QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1, " "), "\d+")),
   "select Col3,Col4"))
  ```

  [image: 0]
- to create duration value:

  ```
  =JOIN(":", QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1, " "), "\d+")),
   "select Col2,Col3,Col4"))+REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\d+")
  ```

  [image: 0]
- to convert on seconds/minutes/hours:

  ```
  =INT(TO_TEXT(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1, " "), "\d+"))),
   "select (Col1*24)+Col2 label (Col1*24)+Col2''")&":"&
   JOIN(":", QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1, " "), "\d+")),
   "select Col3,Col4")))*86400)
  ```

  - for minutes: **`*1440`**
  - for hours: **`*24`**

  [image: 0]